# MySQL: Expanding table columns and insert/update values

Tags: mysql

I need to combine two tables into one.

Table `s_ogr`

```
id | ad | numara | yurt_id |
```

**Current Table** `s_kontrol`

```
id | ogr_id | yurt_id
```

**What is needed** `s_kontrol_k`

```
id | ogr_id | ogr_numara |ogr_ad | yurt_id  `(ogr_id represent the id from s_ogr)`
```

*( `ad = name` , `yurt_id = department_id`, `ogr_id is student_number`(reason of problem, should be student_id)  )*

**My Sittuation**; `s_kontrol` is full of data. I need it to be like `s_kontrol_k` , but new two fields should be taken from `s_ogr` table , by the match operation of s_ogr and s_kontrol (`s_ogr.id=s_kontrol.ogr_id` and `s_ogr.yurt_id =s_kontrol.yurt_id`). Previous mistake was not to add the `ogr_id` as `student_id` into `s_kontrol`

How to create my new `s_kontrol_k` with filled values of new columns. I am able to copy the same values from s_kontrol but could'n achieve to fill new colums

Comment: I'm having difficulty in understanding what, exactly, you mean? Maybe if you gave 1) the data before changes, 2) the data after changes and 3) the logic you used to arrive from point 1 to point 2. Post this data as DML (not as a copy and paste from a `SELECT` or post a graphic).

Comment: You are right I need to learn beautiful asking. But my issue is very easy. Need to add two more column to my original table. With web service script I am joining two table, lately The Query get out of control with its lenght that is why I need simple structure right now. s_kontrol_k is my trial table. I fixed it ty.

Comment: it is **very** important that you add **data** (before - 2 tables, after - 1 table) in the form CREATE TABLE s_ogr (id INTEGER....); and then INSERT INTO s_ogr VALUES (1, .....); - a few records for each table!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand what you want is

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `s_kontrol_k` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `ogr_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `ogr_ad` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `ogr_numara` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `yurt_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    );

    INSERT INTO `s_kontrol_k` (
        SELECT sk.id,sk.ogr_id, so.ad AS ogr_ad,
        so.numara AS ogr_numara, so.yurt_id FROM s_kontrol AS sk
        INNER JOIN s_ogr AS so ON sk.ogr_id = so.id
    );
```

First create the desired table `s_kontrol_k` and copy data from both `s_ogr` and `s_kontrol`  to newly created table `s_kontrol_k`.

I hope this helps..